# SOAP request with SproutCore

Tags: soap, sproutcore

I'm thinking of using sproutcore for a web application and was wondering if anyone had used it with soap? Basically I want to know how easy is it to use sproutcore with soap? Is there anything in their api for soap requests?

Comment: As it currently stands, this is a yes/no question (and you don't want "no" answers). Do you have any other information you'd like to add?

Comment: Specifically I'm trying to use it with the mindbodyapi found here http://www.mindbodyonline.com/api. I want to create an app for clients to login and have a calendar with their class schedules.

Answer (score 1):

Sproutcore doesn't need a special API you talk to.

If you are using the datastore, you implement a SC.Datasource that talks to your server. This can be everything, it's all in your hands.

Answer (score 0):

What backend do you plan on using? For example, if you are going to use .NET; then consume the SOAP with C#/VB whatever, then access the methods through an asmx, wcf, ashx of your choice. PHP again consume in PHP and access with either a POST or GET to a php page.

You are going to need to do this to avoid Cross Domain issues. But javascript isn't made to consume SOAP, because of the cross domain issues and the fact that JSONP needs JSON and not xml.